# Finding the JRE version configured on the build path (programmatically)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Since a user can specify a different JRE from the default one in a Java project, is there any way to find, programmatically, the version of the JRE configured on the project buildpath?

Using the Eclipse API I can find the name (but it's user defined so no information about the version is guaranteed) of the JRE through the classpath, but from there I can see no way to extract information about the version.

The context is that I am doing a verification before a java program is launched within Eclipse, that will require additional files compiled with a certain java version. What i need is to verify if the user has chosen for that project a JRE that is compatible with it. I can do java.version to find the default one in the system, but it doesn't guarantee that the person hasn't chosen a different one for that project in particular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, running `java -version` using the executable in the configured JRE would certainly do the trick. Within an application you can check the system properties...

Comment: That might work. Spent so much time searching around the Eclipse API that didn't even think of more simple solutions. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome, made it an answer, because I cannot see why this should not work...

Answer (score 2):

To find it *programmatically*:

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
```

Or, within ant (build.xml) or maven (pom.xml) as: `${java.version}`

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: That will only give me the version of the default JRE/JDK - but there might be multiple installed and you can define a different one for your eclipse project. The context being an Eclipse plugin, maybe i should have made that more clear.

Comment: When you run it from within a program it will give you the JRE/JDK version that is being used by that program.

Comment: This will give the version your running program is using.  If you want to know what your build tool is using, it can be accessed as ${java.version} in ant or maven.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but they don't really apply to what I need. I am doing a verification before a java program is launched (that will require additional files compiled with a certain java version). What i need is to verify if the user has chosen for that project a JRE that is compatible with it. I can do java.version to find the default one in the system, but it doesn't guarantee that the person hasn't chosen a different one for that project in particular. I'll update my question with these details.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `java -version` from a console using the executable in the configured JRE. It's not directly available from Eclipse, but it should do the trick.

You can choose which JRE to use in the "Run Configurations". By default it will use the library configured in the projects "Build Path". This one chooses the (default) JRE or execution environment in the preferences. You can use the location of the `.jar`s to find the location of the JRE.

You can find your installed JRE's (including the location) and the configuration of the  Execution Environments within the Eclipse preferences: first open "Java" then "Installed JRE's". This should show you the location.

[NOTE]

Normally you choose a execution environment and then configure the runtime to go with it, although you should take care that you can access all the required components if you choose a execution environment instead of directly pointing to a JRE.